# Node.js net tcp buffering memory leak

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, tcp, buffer

I'm writing a TCP game server in Node.js and am having issues with splitting the TCP stream into messages. As i want to read numbers and floats from the buffer i cannot find a suitable module to outsource to as all the ones i've found deal with simple strings ending with a new line delimiter. I decided to go with prefixing each message with the length in bytes of the message. I did this and wrote a simple program to spam the server with random messages ( well constructed with a UInt16LE prefix depicting the length of the message ). I noticed that the longer I leave the programs running my actual server keeps using up more and more memory. I tried using a debugging tool to trace the memory allocation with no success so I figured i'd post my code here and hope for a reply. So here is my code... any tips or pointers as to where I'm going wrong or what I can do differently/more efficiently would be amazing! 
Thanks.

```
server.on("connection", function(socket) {
var session = new sessionCS(socket);
console.log("Connection from " + session.address);

// data buffering variables
var currentBuffer = new Buffer(args.bufSize);
var bufWrite = 0;
var bufRead = 0;
var mSize = null;
var i = 0;

socket.on("data", function(dataBuffer) {

    // check if buffer risk of overflow
    if (bufWrite + dataBuffer.length > args.bufSize-1) {
        var newBufWrite = 0;
        var newBuffer = new Buffer(args.bufSize);

        while(bufRead < bufWrite) {
            newBuffer[newBufWrite] = currentBuffer[bufRead];
            newBufWrite++;
            bufRead++;
        }

        currentBuffer = newBuffer;
        bufWrite = newBufWrite;
        bufRead = 0;
        newBufWrite = null;
    }

    // appending buffer
    for (i=0; i<dataBuffer.length; i++) {
        currentBuffer[bufWrite] = dataBuffer[i];
        bufWrite ++;
    }

    // if beginning of message not acknowleged
    if (mSize === null && (bufWrite - bufRead) >= 2) {
        mSize = currentBuffer.readUInt16LE(bufRead);
    }

    // if difference between read and write is greater or equal to message mSize + 2
    // +2 for the integer holding the message size
    // this means that a full message is in the buffer and needs to be extracted
    while ((bufWrite - bufRead) >= mSize+2) {
        bufRead += 2;
        var messageBuffer = new Buffer(mSize);

        for(i=0; i<messageBuffer.length; i++) {
            messageBuffer[i] = currentBuffer[bufRead];
            bufRead++;
        }

        // this is where the message buffer would be passed to the router
        router(session, messageBuffer);
        messageBuffer = null;

        // seeinf if another message length indicator is in the buffer
        if ((bufWrite - bufRead) >= 2) {
            mSize = currentBuffer.readUInt16LE(bufRead);
        }
        else {
            mSize = null;
        }
    }
});
}
```

Comment: What are you using to measure server memory usage? This can be a tricky thing to measure correctly if not done properly and you can easily be mislead by system caching and paging.

Comment: @jfriend00 im working on my windows 7 so just plain old task manager. im positive there is a leak because if i leav the client spamming the server for about 10-15 minutes the server will be using over 1 gig of memory! and its initial state before the client beginnes spamming is around 50kb.. you could very clearly see it rising

Comment: What does the `router()` function do?  Are you clearing the session reference on a disconnect event?

Comment: @jfriend00 the router function basically diagnoses the type of message it is and sends it to the apropriate event handler (I.e it's a move message or an authentication message/ basically game stuff) and yes I am setting the session variable to null on socket close event , even though it shouldn't really matter as the session variable is created in the scope of on connection which will all get cleared on close anyway .. I will try now to comment out my router function and do the test again to make sure that the leak is specifically within this part of the code

Comment: I am seeing similar behavior for a (net) socket server I am creating. Memory leak is worse in linux than windows. I am not able to find any solution yet though. One suggestion is to set dataBuffer to null at the end, it should be a tiny bit.

Answer (score 0):

Buffer Frame Serialization Protocol (BUFSP) https://github.com/teambition/bufsp 
It may be that you want: encode messages into buffer, write to TCP, receive and splitting the TCP stream buffers into messages.

Comment: Does it also allow messages to be send at the same time (like sending a messages at the same time you are sending a large file)?